# Angular 5 post multiple files

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5. I call a method passing in my array of files. I then iterate over the array posting to the server. When all files are posted I need to return with an array of the results or an observable. The below code is close, I  just need to return when done now. What am I missing? You can see the //DONE, that's when I know I'm done. Thanks for the help.

```
uploadAll(files: any) {
 //console.log(files);
 //httpOptions.reportProgress = true;
 //httpOptions.observe = 'events';
 //const formData = new FormData();
 var results = [];

files.forEach(file => {
  //Create a new multipart-form for every file
  //formData.append('file', file, file.FileName);

  var obs = this.http.post<any>('roots.services/api/documents', file, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
    //map(event => this.getEventMessage(event, file)),
    //tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
    //last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
    catchError(this.handleError(file))
    );

  return obs.subscribe(
    res => {
      //
      results.push(res.status + ', ' + res.statusText + ', ' + file.FileName);

      if (results.length == files.length) {
        //DONE
        console.log(results);
        return results;
      }
    });

});

}
```

Comment: Why not just send all the files in one request?

Comment: Well, cause I was told IIS has a size limitation that it will take. So this is attempting to get around some of that limitation?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware you were using IIS, ignore me. That said, you can always increase the default limit https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb306.aspx

Comment: unless your files are very large, collectively being over 4 gigs, i suggest sending all the files in 1 request. The max you can send, I believe, is 4294967295 bytes, which is ~4.29GB.

Answer (score 0):

what if you loop through and build an array of this.http.post...

then outside the loop do a forkJoin.  this will return all of your posts at once then you just return the forkJoin

example:

```
const calls = [];
files.forEach(file => {
   calls.push(this.http.post<any>('roots.services/api/document', file, httpOptions));
});
return forkJoin(calls);
```

when you subscribe to this it will return an array of results.

Comment: can I get an example?